# restrict wp.media modal to only show files uploaded by current user

Tags: javascript, wordpress, filter, media-library

I have a wordpress plugin where I want to create a custom wp.media modal window for users to upload files from the front end. I want to show only the files that have been uploaded by current user. I am not sure where to start filtering this input. Here is my current javascript wp.media function. I am able to restrict library to a specific file type but I have no clue how to then filter by current_user.

```
function open_media_window() {
var upload = "";
if (this.window === undefined) {

  if($(this).hasClass('bizimg-select')){
    upload = "bizimg";
  }
  if($(this).hasClass('vcard-file')){
    upload = "vcard";
  }

  if(upload=='bizimg'||upload==""){
    this.window = wp.media({
            title: 'Upload my Bizcard Bizimg',
            library: {type: 'image/*',
          uploadedTo : wp.media.view.settings.post.id},
            multiple: false,
            button: {text: 'Insert'}
        });
  }
  if((upload=='vcard')){
    this.window = wp.media({
            title: 'Upload my Bizcard vCard',
            library: {type: 'text/x-vcard'},
            multiple: false,
            button: {text: 'Insert'}
        });
  }

  var self = this; // Needed to retrieve our variable in the anonymous function below
  this.window.on('select', function() {
          var files = self.window.state().get('selection').toArray();
          var first = files[0].toJSON();
          wp.media.editor.insert('[myshortcode id="' + first.id + '"]');
          //populate selected-bizimg-file with file name
          if(upload=='bizimg'){
            //populate bizimg_post with post id
            $('#bizimg_post').val(first["id"]);
            if($('#selected-bizimg-file')){
              $('#selected-bizimg-file').text(first['filename']);
            }
            if('img.bizimg'){
              $('img.bizimg').attr("srcset", first['url']).attr("src", first['url']);
              $('.bizimg-div').removeClass("border-blue");
            }
          }
          //do the same for vcard
          if(upload=='vcard'){
            $('#vcard_post').val(first["id"]);
            if($('#selected-vcard-file')){
              $('#selected-vcard-file').text(first['filename']);
              $('#vcard-raw-textarea').load(first['url']);
              $('#vcard-upload').css('color','#df9e06');
              $('.remove-file').removeClass('daisy-hidden');
            }
          }

      });

 }
    this.window.open();
   return false;
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was rather easy after digging awhile. I would like to attribute the answer to [caldas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5469061/caldas) who answered this in a previous question. 
[wordpress show only media user has uploaded in wp_editor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33247196/7803226)
. If you think this is just a duplicate question, please flag. I thought it was unrelated as I was dealing with a custom wp media modal.